# Finding nearest geographic raster element

Tags: python, geolocation, geospatial

I have a large list of longitude latitude points and want to find the nearest rectangle (so which rectangle contains the point) in a given raster of geographic coordinates.

However, for the raster I only have the centroids of each rectangle (polygon) in the raster. I know though that the rectangles have a size of 250m x 250m.

Just checking for absolute distance or geographic distance to the centers does not work, as the rectangles are not necessarily aligned. I am happy to get ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could generate your raster of geographic coordinates that represent raster cells following this approach: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177061/ascii-file-with-latitude-longitude-and-data-to-geotiff-using-python

And then if you created a shapefile of your latitute and longitude points you could get raster cell ID for each point using this approach:

```
def GetRasterValueAtPoints(rasterfile, shapefile, fieldname):
'''
__author__ =   "Marc Weber <weber.marc@epa.gov>"
Original code attribution: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/46898/2856
returns raster values at points in a point shapefile
assumes same projection in shapefile and raster file
Arguments
---------
rasterfile        : a raster file with full pathname and extension
shapefile         : a shapefile with full pathname and extension
fieldname         : field name in the shapefile to identify values
'''
src_ds=gdal.Open(rasterfile)
no_data = src_ds.GetRasterBand(1).GetNoDataValue()
gt=src_ds.GetGeoTransform()
rb=src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=(fieldname, "RasterVal"))
i = 0
ds=ogr.Open(shapefile)
lyr=ds.GetLayer()

for feat in lyr:
    geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
    name = feat.GetField(fieldname)
    mx,my=geom.GetX(), geom.GetY()  #coord in map units

    #Convert from map to pixel coordinates.
    #Only works for geotransforms with no rotation.
    px = int((mx - gt[0]) / gt[1]) #x pixel
    py = int((my - gt[3]) / gt[5]) #y pixel

    intval = rb.ReadAsArray(px,py,1,1)
    if intval == no_data:
        intval = -9999
    df.set_value(i,fieldname,name) 
    df.set_value(i,"RasterVal",float(intval)) 
    i+=1
return df
```